# python how to pass array value into file open request

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

Hi guys I want to be able to pass a list of words into a for loop, how can I make the code below work

```
list = ['word1','word2','word3']
for x in list
      with open('folder/{x}.txt') as fin:
      do something()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? why name your variable `list`?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a list of words into a `for` loop"? You don't pass things into loops. What do you mean by "work"—what exactly are you trying to do with the (invalid) code that you posted, and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
word_list = ['word1','word2','word3']
for x in word_list:
    with open('folder/{x}.txt'.format(x=x)) as fin:
         do something()
```

The two changes I made:

- Add a forgotten colon after the for statement
- Add `.format(x=x)` to the string. This is python's [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) mechanism

Comment: perfect! thanks so much, going to mark right when timelimit passes

Comment: Curious as to why this has been downvoted - seems to answer the question.

Comment: Hmm...there's 2 downvotes...probably because this is a code-only answer. rtemperv, code-only answers (means there's only a (working) code in the answer) aren't very helpful. Please explain "How and why does your code work, and why doesn't OP's code work (sometimes)" .

Comment: I originally downvoted it because you didn't add the colon. I reversed this, although you call it a semicolon.

Comment: Usual request: Fix bad (read: builtin stomping) variable names when you're fixing code. A variable named `list` is a headache waiting to happen.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a colon.  The `with` clause needs some work, as well.  Here's how to fix the colon part at the end of the `for` loop:

```
list = ['word1','word2','word3']
for x in list:
    print(x)
```